# Call global variable within a class

Tags: php

```
class test() {

  function get_signup($user)
  {
     global $hostid;
     foreach ($hostname as $host)
     {
       $hostid = $host->id;
     }
     return $hostid;
  }

  function get_login($user)
  {
     global $hostid;
     // get_signup($user);
     echo $hostid;
  } 
}
```

Is that possible to pass a variable globally from one function to another without calling get_signup($user).

Comment: it is possible using global variables, what do you mean however without "calling" `get_signup()`? When you do not call the method the code inside of it is not executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the global variable from anywhere. But here you will get empty result as you are not calling get_signup($user), so $hostid is not assigned value. You can write script this way :

```
class test() {
    private $hostid;
    function get_signup($user)
    {
        foreach ($hostname as $host)
        {
            $this->hostid = $host->id;
        }
        return $this->hostid;
    }

    function get_login($user)
    {
        echo $this->hostid;
    } 
}
```